# How to used Application Context in Dagger in object class kotlin

Tags: android, socket.io, kotlin, dagger-2

How to used Application Context in Dagger2

```
    @Module
class AppModule(private val app: App) {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @AppContextQualifier
    fun provideApplication(): App = app
}
```

in class like

```
object SocketConnection  {

 private fun listenSocketEvents() {

    socket?.on(SocketContent.JOINED, { args ->
       //Toast.makeText(context!!,"logout",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    })
}
}
```

I want to toast when socket listens to any data. so need to provide a context how to get dagger application context in an object class.

Is this possible or there is another way to achieve??

Comment: Check this article to gain complete understanding of Dagger 2 https://medium.com/@tpom6oh/dependency-injection-on-android-with-dagger-2-full-learning-path-eda0632bd684

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `object SocketConnection  {`

should be

```
@Singleton 
class SocketConnection @Inject constructor(
   @AppContextQualifier private val app: App
) {
     private fun listenSocketEvents() {
        socket?.on(SocketContent.JOINED, { args ->
           Toast.makeText(app,"logout",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        })
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the Kotlin `object` keyword to make an equivalent of a static singleton when you are using Dagger 2 is not necessary. Dagger 2 has a more flexible management of scopes than manually declaring singletons through the Kotlin `object` keyword and all the dependencies you provide in your `AppModule` will effectively end up as app-scoped singletons.

If your `SocketConnection` is intended to be a singleton, make it a `class` provided in your `AppModule` or another module with `@Singleton` scope:

```
class SocketConnection constructor(private val app: App) {

   private fun listenSocketEvents() {
       //
   }
}
```

Annotate the constructor with `@Inject` or alternatively if you want to provide it in your `AppModule`:

```
@Module
class AppModule(private val app: App) {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideSocketConnection(app: App): SocketConnection =
        SocketConection(app)

}
```